# Appengine "copy to another app" job do not stop (After 3 weeks)

Tags: google-app-engine

I set up a staging envierment to a web app I created about 3 weeks ago, 
and I tried to transfer the data from the production envierment that was 
already set up using the Copy data to another app in the datastore admin.

The data was indeed copied to my staging envierment. The problem was that 
the copy jobs are still running, 3 weeks after they were fired! (It took the data
about 3 hours to transfer to my staging evnierment. )

I tried to cancel the jobs using the abort option, with no luck.

As for now, 7 out of the 14 jobs are listed as completed, and the others are
listed as active. My /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback handler is bombarded with 
3.1 posts per second, and I think it got to a point it is harming my site performance, not to mention costing me money...

How do I get the tasks to abort?

Answer (score 1):

You can purge your task queues from the normal datastore admin task queues section.  That will force the jobs to stop.

You can clean up the mapreduce jobs by deleting the entities they store in the datastore to keep track of their progress - they are called "mr_progress" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where DataStore Admin tasks would not die. The tasks were from a copy and / or backup operation. Aborting the jobs didn't do anything for me, either. Even after going into the task queue and purging the queue, the tasks would reappear. I did all of the following to keep the tasks dead (not sure if all steps are necessary!):

1. Paused the task queue (click task Queues, and then the queue in question).
2. Purged the queue (clicking purge repeatedly)
3. Went into the datastore viewer and deleted all DatastoreAdmin entries with Active status, and MapReduce items. I'm not sure if this is necessary.
4. Changed the queue.yaml file to include a task_age_limit of 10s and task_retry_limit of 3 under the retry_parameters.

I originally was trying to do a large backup and copy to another app at the same time, during which the destination app ran into a quota. Not sure if this caused the issues. Riley Lark's answer got me started.

One other addition: when I went into the task queue and clicked the task name to expand the details, nothing ever loaded into the "Headers", "Raw Payload", etc. tabs. They just said "loading..."